# Alternative to inline-block and its support with current browsers

Tags: css

So I am currently using `inline-block` for my site.  I understand it's still relatively new (scope of 5 years).  I was wondering if it's become okay to use it these days or if someone can recommend me an elegant hack, that would be awesome.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually make the `inline-block` cross browser, you must have missed **[this great article](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/)**.

Answer (score 1):

[`inline-block`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock) is supported in older browsers within certain constraints:

> In IE 6 and 7 inline-block works only
>   on elements that have a natural
>   display: inline.
>
> Firefox 2 and lower don't support this
>   value. You can use -moz-inline-box,
>   but be aware that it's not the same as
>   inline-block, and it may not work as
>   you expect in some situations.

So just use it on natural inline elements like images and spans and you should be fine.

Comment: References: [Quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html#inlineblock) and [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block)