# Can I center a <ul> with left-aligned <li>s?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to center a list of left-aligned items.

This is what I currently have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Shrinkwrapped List</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #wrapper {
        margin: auto;
        width: 500px;
        border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
      }
      #header {
        text-align: center;
       font-size: 200%;
      }
      #content {
        text-align: center;
      }
      #content ul {
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 150%;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 20px auto;
        padding: 0px;
        border: solid 1px #666666;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
        Shrinkwrapped List
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          <li>Dolor sit amet</li>
          <li>Consectetur</li>
          <li>Adipiscing elit</li>
          <li>Morbi odio</li>
          <li>Mi blandit vehicula</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which produces a page that looks like:

[image: Not really what I want]

What I really want looks like this:

[image: This is the look I want]

I can accomplish this by adding `width: 200px;` to `#content ul` but the problem is that I have a lot of lists like this and they all have various widths.

I'd like the `<ul>` to shrink to the content so it can be centered correctly. Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

---

## Solution

Thanks to [KennyTM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm) and [Magnar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123/magnar), here is the solution:

Add these four lines to `#content ul`'s CSS rules:

```
display:-moz-inline-stack;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
```

I've tested this in IE6, IE7, IE8 and Firefox 3.6. The results looks like the second image above and the list always fits to the content of the items.

Comment: I realize this is an unpopular idea, but wouldn't this be easier with a table?

Comment: It would also be easier to individually give them widths. You can do a class one for 99% of the styling of the element, then another class just for the individual widths. http://www.search-this.com/2007/04/25/optimize-your-css-with-multi-class-elements/

Comment: Check out the link in the best answer here. It's way to get inline-block to work in older browsers, but it sure does look like a pain. http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/ Link taken from the best answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316535/alternative-to-inline-block-and-its-support-with-current-browsers

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Set the `<ul>` to use `display: inline-block;`. See http://jsbin.com/atizi4.

Note that `inline-block` is not supported (completely) for IE ≤7.

Comment: `display: inline-block` works **perfectly** here. Unfortunately, most of my users are using either IE6 or 7. Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: Then you'll be happy to know that IE supports inline-block if you add hasLayout to an element, and then set it to display: inline after. Here's the hack: http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/

Comment: Thanks KennyTM and Magnar. Combining the information in your answer & comment, I was able to solve my problem. The fix is very easy. I updated my answer to include the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably adopt [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030121/how-can-i-center-a-box-of-unknown-width-in-css). Inline-block for IE, display:table for modern browsers. Might need to explicitly specify a list-style-type.

Edit: Since this is a list, may be able to get away with `inline-block` on the `ul` and not display:table. **You need to declare in a separate rule, `display:inline;` after `inline-block` for IE.**

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using CSS and putting a `margin: 0 auto` on the `<ul>` with a maximum width container.

Comment: If you do this, I think that if your ul is only 100px for example, but your maximum width container is 200px, the li's will not look centered in the page, but rather left aligned inside the 200px width ul. 

see what i'm talking about here http://jsbin.com/ubege

Comment: Both of those are already done in the example provided in the question. `#content ul` has `margin: 20px auto` and its container div `#content` has is maximum width by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It involves in incompatibilities, but I don't really know how older browsers handle margins and padding and all that anymore since I only work with new ones. It only involves some minor changes to your CSS.

```
/* I didn't style the other parts, so I'm taking them out to save space. */

#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content ul {
    border-top: solid 1px #666666;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #666666;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 150%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 202px;
}

#content li {
    border-left: solid 1px #666666;
    border-right: solid 1px #666666;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**Edit:** I want to clarify what I changed. I changed how content is aligned, but honestly, you can change that back, I don't think it has an effect.

What I originally did was set a fixed width and centered your `li` element, which you had no styling for. That just centered the content. The border you placed was on the `ul` so it was very wide, but if we placed it in the `li` then we would have many boxes. So, I split the border style. The reason why `#content ul` has a 202px width is because borders count on the outside of the width.

I hope the explanation made it clear to why it worked. Good luck! I tested this out in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

A solution compatible with any browser, no matter how old it is:
Center the table and put your list inside.

Example:

```
<table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"><tr><td>
<ul>
  <li>Line1</li>
  <li>Line test 2</li>
  <li>Line long for test</li>
</ul>
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: are you aware that this question is 12 years old?

Comment: Yes, I saw before you asked me. But that is another solution. It is not the most elegant but it is a solution that works even on the oldest browsers and is different from those proposed above.