# Center UL but keep text left aligned

Tags: html, css

Here is what I'm trying to achieve, text is centered but starting at the same point:

http://gi.zaley.in:8080/14/11/04/5459047ac35cd/N5459048577c8c.png

What I've got:

http://gi.zaley.in:8080/14/11/04/545904daf36ef/C545904df5f484.png

So, text centered well, but how can I make captions start from the one point? (like 1st image)

```
<ul class="_unstyled_ _left_">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="-avatar _round_ _normal">
            <figure class="-thumbnail">
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/krystalfister/128.jpg" alt="Krystalfister">
            </figure>
        </a>
        <p class="name">Random Guy</p>
        <p class="points">9 876 / 10 000 points</p>
    </li>
    <li>i hate</li>
    <li>goddamn</li>
    <li>markup</li>
    <li>go die</li>
</ul>
```

I don't list my CSS here, cause it's obvious just text-align: center;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355058/can-i-center-a-ul-with-left-aligned-lis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this:

```
ul {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100px;
}
li {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20%;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/br5ff7L7/)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
._unstyled_ _left_ {
    text-align: center; 
}

._unstyled_ _left_ li {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: This does not work, it has the same effect of only left aligning the li.