# Bootstrap3 align text left but keep the text block centered

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a menu that I want to be exactly under the logo no matter what the screen size. Until the screen becomes small enough for mobile devices then it turns into a hamburger menu.

It works fine with centered text: http://new2015.wingsofsupport.org/ So when you make the screen bigger and smaller the centered text will remain exactly under the logo.

Problem is that I want the text itself to be aligned left but remain exactly under the logo. If I do a "text-align: left;" and the give it a margin to fit nicely under the logo it's starts moving all over the place once I change the screen size.

My Google-Fu is letting me down and other solutions I found on Stack like this one: [Center UL but keep text left aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740784/center-ul-but-keep-text-left-aligned) aren't doing the job for me.

Comment: Can you post your HTML & CSS?

Comment: The problem is that the logo scales down in size. So even with a few modifications, the text loses its relative placement when the image scales down. I suggest using fixed sizes instead of percentages, and then breaking them down with media queries. This way, you can fine-tune the text placement and logo size throughout the browser breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
ul {display: block; width: 100px; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: auto;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```