# Trying to center UL

Tags: css, alignment, html-lists, centering

I am trying to properly center a UL. Even though I used display:table and the correct margin: 0 auto... still it doesn't work properly. It doesn't go the center.

What am I doing wrong?

CSS for the UL and the LI

```
.container { 
    position: relative; 
    display:table; 
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}


.container li {
    margin: 30px 30px;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    width: 310px;
    height: 370px;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Here is the LIVE version. When adjusting the page you will notice that the UL is docked to the left side of the page.

**UPDATED**
http://codepen.io/mariomez/pen/doJvJz?editors=010

**Notes: the problem is almost resolved. The only issue is that the LI components are also center aligned which is not visually good for me. How can I align them to the left and keep the UL centered?**

Answer (score 1):

Position the `.container` with `text-align: center;`, disable floating the list elements and use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: inline;` for them:

```
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}


.container li {
    margin: 30px 30px;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: none;
    width: 310px;
    height: 370px;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qhxxn24/)

Comment: thank you very much! The only issue is that the li components are also aligned to the center which is not visually good for me. How can I align them to the left and still have the whole UL centered?

Comment: What is your goal then? You want to center an element (`<ul>`), which has the width of 100 % to the window so it generally never is really centered. You can’t center an element, which has 100 % width of the window.

Comment: Something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355058/can-i-center-a-ul-with-left-aligned-lis

Comment: I tried to apply the solution but it's messing the hidden elements.

Comment: My goal is having a ul list centered - related to the page... but having the li aligned to the left - related to the ul.